# PHP MySQL returns different values when run in phpmyadmin and in a script

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two functions pulling product_ids from our database. The "topSellers" function SQL returns the expected results in phpmyadmin, but when run from the script it has an unexpected (to me) output.

```
function topSellers(){
    $db = \Skeet\DatabaseFactory::getDatabase(FRAMEWORK_DB);
    $sql = "SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS totalCount FROM order_line WHERE creation_datetime > '" .  date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-30 days")) . "' AND is_retired = 0 GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY totalCount DESC LIMIT 20";
    echo $sql;
    $rows = $db->doQuery($sql)->getResultAsArray();      
    var_dump($rows);    
    return $rows;
}
function newProducts(){ // Works great
    $db = \Skeet\DatabaseFactory::getDatabase(FRAMEWORK_DB);
    $sql = "SELECT product_id FROM product WHERE creation_datetime > '" .  date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-90 days')) . "' AND product_name NOT LIKE '%Build_Bundled_Package%' AND price > 0 AND is_retired = 0 ORDER BY creation_datetime DESC LIMIT 20";   
    $rows = $db->doQuery($sql)->getResultAsArray();   

    return $rows;
}
```

The $sql printed is:

```
SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS totalCount FROM order_line WHERE creation_datetime > '2015-06-20' AND is_retired = 0 GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY totalCount DESC LIMIT 20
```

in phpmyadmin it returns the two columns sorted counted and sorted with 20 rows.

When run from the site it returns an empty array. Or if I try for an object:

```
object(Skeet\Database\MysqliDatabaseResult)#932 (1) {
  ["result":protected]=>
  object(mysqli_result)#98 (5) {
    ["current_field"]=>
    int(0)
    ["field_count"]=>
    int(2)
    ["lengths"]=>
    NULL
    ["num_rows"]=>
    int(0)
    ["type"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

This Ended up working:

```
function topSellers(){
   $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-30 days"));        

  try {  
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=******', DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT product_id, count(quantity) AS totalCount FROM order_line WHERE creation_datetime > :date GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY totalCount DESC');
    $stmt->execute(array(':date' => $date));    

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }



return $result;
}
```

Comment: well, one's -30 days and one's -90 days. did you check if you actually have any records that are less than 30 days old? and note that you don't need to generate the date in php. `where creation_datetime > now() - interval 30 day` works just as well directly in mysql.

Comment: Are you using PDO or `mysqli`? If so, I strongly encourage you to use *prepared statements* and avoid composing your queries with string concatenation.

Comment: is `creation_datetime` is just date or both datetime?

Comment: @MarcB We do have sales in the last 30 days. Our "top seller" has 107 sales instances in the last 30 days.

Comment: @shehary datetime. "2015-07-21 11:04:11"

Comment: @KevinGreene and in your query `date("Y-m-d",strtotime("-30 days"))` output `2015-06-21` so don't you think this is the reason why not getting the desired result when in your database `datetime. 2015-07-21 11:04:11`

Comment: @shehary The exact same line works in the newProducts function. Also, when in the database I do get the result I expect.

Comment: the query is different in newProduct function and it doesn't matter you get the correct result when run in phpmyadmin dealing with datetime because couple of week back i faced same row count problem,  in php result not accurate and same query in phpmyadmin working, i was searching between 2 date range with `between` and when i replace between with `>=` and `<=` i got the accurate result in php and phpmyadmin both, in my case i assign datetime to variable and then declaring that varibale in query like `$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime());` and in query creation_datetime > '".$date." 00:00:00'

Comment: and i highly suggest use `>=` instead just `>`